# tufte quotation marks in texshop misbehave

Tags: punctuation, tufte

In tutfte-book class, using texshop the quotation marks in `fish' and ``fowl'' come out 'fish' and ''fowl'' with a positive tilt (/). Any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By default the `tufte-book` class uses Palatino, that has very peculiar quote characters.